# HTML isn't centered properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

https://fast-fortress-5770.herokuapp.com/

just need some hand holding to get the h1 element Yo! Justin here. and the h3 element I'm all over this web thing to be responsive, but also centered, too. however, struggling with this, so I'd be grateful if one could lend hand. Many thanks.

```css
    .section {
     text-align: center;
     margin:0!important;
     padding:0!important;
    }
    #floater {
     margin-top: 23% 0;
     margin-left: 39% 0;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="section" id="floater">
      <h1><strong>Yo! Justin here.</strong></h1>
      <h3>I'm all over this web thing.</h3>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please post code (not just a link).

Comment: Also, your page centers the text for me. I can't replicate your error.

Comment: Almost there lil buddy. Edit your question to include the code. Probably your CSS as well.

Comment: What has to do with css3?

Answer (score 0):

```
#floater
{
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

add this piece of css in place of the code you have for #floter. this should work for most of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can either assign text-align: center to your h1 and h3 or you can add

```
.section {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

A div is not text so it cannot use text-align.

Comment: That's fine for a block that's centered on the page. However his <h*> is a full-width element with text centered inside.

Answer (score 0):

When you have code that is this small a fast way to debug it would be to remove css line by line (you can comment out a line really quick if you don't want to delete it).

```
.section {  text-align: center;  
margin:0!important; 
padding:0!important; }
#floater {  margin-top: 23% 0;  
margin-left: 39% 0; }
```

for instance:

```
.section {  text-align: center;  
/*  margin:0!important; */
padding:0!important; }
#floater {  margin-top: 23% 0;  
margin-left: 39% 0; }
```